# How to fit tabs according to screen size / browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a 4 tabs which I have showed below. It keeps moving as the screen size changes and with different browsers. I see **about.html** going down each time I open it on different computers it doesn't stay on a single line tab. I need to keep changing my `width:303px`.

Actually I need to reduce it on different computers and browsers. Whats the best way to fix this so that it stays on a single line with rest of the tabs.

**css**

```
 ul 
 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 li 
 {
   float: left;
 }


a:link, a:visited {
  display: block;
  width:303px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="offers.html">Offers</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a><li>
  <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with "bootstrapping"?

Comment: You should use percentage widths. If you have 5 tabs then change it to 20% width.

Comment: Edited not required for this page .

Comment: Do you want that all the links will be in the same line (horizontal nav)?

Comment: yes it need to be in horizontal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options that will space and align these ***without*** explicit widths (either % or actual px/em etc values):

**CSS Tables** (Green Version) - [**Support IE8 and above**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

```
ul.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.table li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

**Flexbox** (Plum Version) - [**Support IE10 and above**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```
ul.flex {
  display: flex;
}

ul.flex li {
  flex:1;
}
```

Demo of both

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
ul.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.table li {
  display: table-cell;
}
ul.flex {
  display: flex;
}
ul.flex li {
  flex: 1;
}
ul.flex a {
  background: plum;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul class="table">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="offers.html">Offers</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="links.html">Links</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About us</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="offers.html">Offers</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="links.html">Links</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note: This is not a one-stop solution. At some point the screen may not be wide enough to hold all the text. At that point you need media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `calc()` function....

`width: calc(100% / X);`

Where **X** is the number of tabs.

You can also use....

`width: calc((100% / X) - Ypx);`

Where **Y** is the sum amount of padding, margin, or space you want between tabs.

So for 4 tabs with `margin: 0 5px;` between them and a 1px border on them, you'd use:

`width: calc((100% / 4) - 48px);`

[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)